# ASP.NET MVC, how to combine Razor Authorization Roles with an Angular9+ / React or similar NodeJS/Webpack Based fronentend framework

Tags: jquery, angular, asp.net-mvc, razor, role-base-authorization

In our application, we have a complex hierarchy of user roles for different functionality.
It contains both the Razor and Javascript for these role specific functions.

We want to try to migrate to a frontend framework like Angular 9+ or ReactJS while using
compiled Razor pages for roles based authorization and security.

The hope that, for a regular user, none of the role specific Angular or React code should even be visible, even while inspecting the page and checking the sources section.

Is this even possible with Angular9+ / React ? If so, what would some approaches be ?

As an example we have JQuery and Razor tied to specific role based functions, below:-

```
@Model ReportsVM

@if (User.IsInRole("ReportAdmin"))
{
  @section scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var showPercentage = '@ViewBag.ShowPercentage'; // this is configured elsewhere and stored in session

      $(function(){

        function checkProgress(){
        
          var url = "@Url.Action("CheckProgress", "Reports")?showPercentage=" + showPercentage;

          $.get( url, function( data ) {
            $( ".result" ).append( data );
          });
        }
      
      })
    
    </script>

  }
}

<div class="container">

   @if (User.IsInRole("ReportAdmin"))
   {
      <span class="result"></span>
      <button onclick="checkProgress()" />

      // also, some upload functionality for report admins...
   }     
  <ul class="list_group">

    @for(int x = 0; x < Model.Reports.Count(); x++)
    {
      <li class="list_group_item">
        @Html.ActionLink("Reports", "Index", new { reportId = Model.Reports[x].Id })
      </li>
    }
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This could be useful: https://blog.drinkbird.com/aspnet-mvc-angular-razor-templates I never did it yself but it looks like a way to do it.

Comment: I've seen that one, unfortunately it refers to the old `AngularJS` not the new `Angular 9+`. The old `AngularJS` can be added without `NodeJS/Grunt/Webpack` etc...